# WiFi range extender

Tags: wifi-configuration, wireless-extender

I had a WiFi range extender that worked properly. But suddenly the connection of the extender dropped and even though it seems connected and my devices can connect to it, no data is being transferred so it looks like it is now useless. What should I do?  I have tried formatting the device and setting it up again at least 5 times from different platforms each time. Here is how it looks on my phone.  The model of the extender is a d-link N300 DAP-1320.

[image]

What else should I try?

Comment: I just suggest you reset and then reconfiguration of the extender to connect to your network.